# The terminal process terminated with exit code:1 Is there any way To fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'am trying to compile a basic "Hello World" code in Visual Studio Code. But I'm new at coding, so I can't understand what does "The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1" means.

This is my task.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This one is c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}/",
                     "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"

                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }

        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And this is the program I'm trying to execute:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please don't onhold this question, I'm new at the site so if there's anything wrong about the post please write it down.

Comment: What terminal process ended? The compile process or your program? Do you get error messages?

Comment: The C++ code is valid, who knows what all that JSON stuff is? That is a VSCode build configuration thing I guess? If you run your code from the IDE it will launch a terminal process to run it from, it is presumably that that is returning 1 because your code does not.  The JSON stuff appears to relate only to building your code, not executing it.

Comment: it's the setting files for VSCode

Comment: If you compile this program with `C:\MinGW\bin\g++ -o main.exe main.cpp` and then execute it with `main.exe` it should just work. So unless that doesn't work your problem is with VScode, not C++.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand anything.I am a beginner at this stuff. Can you guys make it simple for me? I would appreciate that.

Comment: Open the Command Prompt. Use the cd command to get to the directory where your C++ source file is. Then run the command @Giel gave you but replace "main.cpp" with the name of your source file. Then run the command `./main.exe`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an error, you should google the error message.
[First hit](https://loekvandenouweland.com/content/the-terminal-process-terminated-with-exit-code-1.html), which comes down to: VSCode cannot find the compiler. VSCode is just an IDE: it doesn't ship with a compiler.

Read [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) on how to setup VSCode to work with C++.